# I want to get drowpdown value from repeater in code how to get it in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="Repeater1_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%#subtypes.FindByPk(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("SubitemID"))).title%></td>
            <td><%#Eval("quantity")%></td>
            <td><%#ThanaRecord.FindByPk(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Thanaid"))).title%></td>
            <td><%#Eval("created_at")%></td>
            <td> <% if (Employee.GetCurrentEmployee().role == "Admin") { %>
                <a href="AddDemand.aspx?type=update&id=<%#Eval("id")%>">EDIT</a>

                    <a href="AddDemand.aspx?type=delete&id=<%#Eval("id")%>">DELETE</a>
                <% } %>
            <%if (Employee.GetCurrentEmployee().role == "SuperVisor")
               { %>
              <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="120px"  CssClass="form-control">
        <asp:ListItem>Accept</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Reject</asp:ListItem>

    </asp:DropDownList>
                <%--<asp:textbox runat="server" id="textTest"></asp:textbox>--%>
            </td>
            <%} %>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you want to access it? However, in general you have to use `RepeaterItem.FindControl("DropDownID")` to get the reference.

For example in `ItemDataBound`:

```
protected void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        DropDownList ddldrop = (DropDownList) e.Item.FindControl("DropDownList1");
        // here you are
    }
}
```

If you want to access it from a button-click handler where the button is outside of the repeater you can loop all the items via `repeater.Items`. You don't need to check the `ListItemType` as in the code above if you loop the repeater-items since `repater.Items` only returns items with type `Item` and `AlternatingItem`.

Comment: I basically want dropdown selected item and then apply condition to it

Comment: @HishamShahid: voila.

Comment: Now It will find dropdown list control but how to find its selected value?

Comment: @HishamShahid: `ddldrop.SelectedValue` ?

Comment: I want to call a function immediately as the user select any item from dropdown on page postback how to do it?

Comment: You have to handle it's `SelectedIndexChangedEvent`. But note that you must not databind the repeater on every postback (f.e. in `Page_Load`) but only `if(!IsPostBack)`.

Comment: But in dropdownlist selected index change event again the same problem arises of how to find dropdown value from repeater inside dropdownlist selected index change event?

Comment: @HishamShahid: if you are in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event you can simply cast the `sender` argument to `DropDownList` ;)